# Why is Firefox complaining about a semicolon in this javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, firefox

So I have this really basic function with a for loop.  It runs fine on modern Chrome and Firefox browsers, but not on a particularly picky Firefox 38 browser.  According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) this function has been supported since Firefox 13.

```
function showhide_class(cl) {
  var es = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
  for(let e of es) {
  e.style.display = (e.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
  }
}
```

The exact error being reported by Firefox is:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer
```

So, why is this error being reported and do you know of a work around? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Delosdos it's the new for...of loop introduced with ECMAScript2015. Maybe it doesn't like the lack of space after for? There could also be a syntax error earlier in the document that is giving an invalid error. Is this the only function in your script tag?

Comment: @Jecoms Ah, yes - I'm guessing his browser doesn't support `for - of`  then in that case?  He'll need a polyfill?

Comment: It should be supported. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility). It's probably a stray error earlier in the document that the other browsers ignore and firefox doesn't.

Comment: That same exact code works fine in Firefox 47 on Windows 8.1... You'd have to dig into the bug list to see if perhaps there was a bug in FF 38 that was fixed later on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `let` statement is the problem. Use `for (var e of es)` instead.

According to MDN, the `let` statement did not get support in Firefox until version 44.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: There it is. If only browser errors would be more helpful ;).

Comment: As someone who works in a company where some people are still using FF 39 (current version is 63), this answer was invaluable.